# 'LOG_LEVEL' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

ive tried everything and i still cant get it to work and chatgpt sucks! This is my logger.js file

```
    // src/logger.js
process.env.LOG_LEVEL = 'debug';

// Use `info` as our standard log level if not specified
const options = { level: process.env.LOG_LEVEL || 'info' };

// If we're doing `debug` logging, make the logs easier to read
if (options.level === 'debug') {
  // https://github.com/pinojs/pino-pretty
  options.transport = {
    target: 'pino-pretty',
    options: {
      colorize: true,
    },
  };
}

// Create and export a Pino Logger instance:
// https://getpino.io/#/docs/api?id=logger
module.exports = require('pino')(options);
```

please help someone

Comment: are you sure this file is the source of the error? Doesn't look like this javascript is trying to execut LOG_LEVEL as an internal or external command, nor as an operable or batch file ... I think the issue is somewhere else